# Excluir um item e adicionando novamente começando índice por contar 1 {ERRO}

Tags: javascript, html

Quando você adiciona **nome, idade e a quantidade** vai contar pelo **índice** ,mas quando você clica prar **excluir** apaga tudo **quantidade fica = 0** , **nome e idade =  por "vazios"**
ai certinho, mas quando adiciono novamente, **a quantidade começa por 2 (índice)** mas quero começar por 1

***Por que ficou por 2 ?***

tentei varias coisas aqui não sei o que fazer, o que faço?

```js
let a = []

function adicionar() {
  var nome = document.getElementById("nome")
  var idade = document.getElementById("idade")
  var r = document.getElementById("res")
  if (nome.value == "" && idade.value) {
    alert("Por favor digite o seu nome e sua idade!")
  }
  if (nome.value.length && idade.value.length) {
    a.push(nome)
    r.innerHTML += ` <tr><th scope="row">${a.length}</th><td>${nome.value}</td><td>${idade.value}</td>`
  }
}


function excluir() {
  var n = [nome, idade]
  v = "vazio"
  z = []
  z.slice(n)
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = `<th scope="row">${z.length}</th><td>${v}</td><td>${v}</td>`
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center mt-3">
    Agenda
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Quantidade</th>
        <th scope="col">Nome</th>
        <th scope="col">Idade</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="res">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="container text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="excluir()">Excluir</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" onclick="editar()">Editar</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="text-center mt-2 mb-4">Adicione por aqui!</h1>
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="NOME">
    <input type="number" name="idade" id="idade" placeholder="IDADE">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btn" onclick="adicionar()">Adicionar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostra `2` porque a função `excluir` não muda o array `a` (ele continua tendo os elementos, o problema é que a função `adicionar` só adiciona os dados no array, porém imprime apenas o último adicionado).

Se a ideia da função `excluir` é limpar tudo, então basta zerar o array (atribua a um array vazio, por exemplo).

Eu também deixaria uma função separada para atualizar a tabela.

```js
let dados = [];

function adicionar() {
  var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
  var idade = document.getElementById("idade").value;
  if (nome == "" || idade == "") {
    alert("Por favor digite o seu nome e sua idade!");
    return; // se não foi preenchido, sai da função
  }
  // se está ok, adiciona nos dados
  dados.push({ nome, idade });
  atualizaTabela();
}

function excluir() {
  dados = [];
  atualizaTabela();
}

function atualizaTabela() {
  var r = document.getElementById("res");
  if (dados.length == 0) {
    r.innerHTML = '<tr><th scope="row">0</th><td>vazio</td><td>vazio</td>';
  } else {
    r.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
      r.innerHTML += `<tr><th scope="row">${i + 1}</th><td>${dados[i].nome}</td><td>${dados[i].idade}</td>`;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center mt-3">
    Agenda
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Quantidade</th>
        <th scope="col">Nome</th>
        <th scope="col">Idade</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="res">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="container text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="excluir()">Excluir</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" onclick="editar()">Editar</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="text-center mt-2 mb-4">Adicione por aqui!</h1>
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="NOME">
    <input type="number" name="idade" id="idade" placeholder="IDADE">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btn" onclick="adicionar()">Adicionar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Mudei o nome do array para `dados` (ainda é meio genérico, mas é melhor do que `a`, que não diz nada sobre o que é o array). Pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

E também coloquei ponto-e-vírgula no final das linhas. Pode parecer "frescura", e sei que o JavaScript "aceita" o código sem ponto e vírgula e "funciona", mas isso evita algumas situações bizarras que podem ocorrer se você não usá-los, como [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596) e [essa](/q/432960/112052) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](/q/3341/112052)).

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela sua educação e dicas!

Comment: @JulioS Aí é o caso de [fazer outra pergunta](/questions/ask), mas enfim, tem várias formas de fazer, depende do que você precisa (por exemplo, vc precisaria escolher qual vai editar, então teria que ter um campo pra isso, etc)

Comment: @JulioS Mas se já tiver adicionado vários, como vc vai saber qual mudar? O usuário tem que escolher o número, e só depois mudar os dados daquele registro específico

Comment: @JulioS Só pra vc ter uma ideia de como ficaria: https://jsfiddle.net/7pg5ks9t/

Comment: É mais e menos isso , vou fazer no input mas muito obrigado me der uma ideia! , sou iniciante e estou praticando js